# Why can't drag inside of scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

It has box with yellow, that is `html object`. The box is draggable by using `Jquery`. When I added `overflow: scroll;` on `CSS`, it don't drag out of scroll that in `div`.

There are some same problems in stackoverflow. But, it didn't solve for my problem.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#box1").draggable({
    snap: ".img_truck_case,#box1",
    snapTolerance: 10,
    containment: ".wrapper",
    revert: true
  });
  $(".img_truck_case").droppable({

    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $("#box1").draggable({
        revert: false
      })
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 700px;
  height: 550px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  border: 2px solid;
  margin-left: 100px;
}

#truck {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 520px;
  left: 300px;
  top: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.left_box_side {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 220px;
  left: 20px;
  top: 2px;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.box {
  width: 60px;
  height: 57px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 57px;
  cursor: default;
  z-index: 9;
  border: 1px solid;
  background-color: #FAD7A0;
}

#box1 {
  left: 20px;
  top: 50px;
}

.img_truck_case {
  position: absolute;
  width: 175px;
  height: 133px;
  top: 117px;
  left: 107px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-eEa1kEtgK9ZL6h60VXwDsJ2rxYCwfxi40VZ9E0XwoEA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left_box_side">
      <div id="box1" class="box">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="truck">
      <img class="img_truck_first" />
      <img class="img_truck_second" />
      <img class="img_truck_case" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bpavd7xL/13/).

How can solve this problem?

Comment: @Tschallacka I added JSFiddle link. But if you want I can add my all code?

Answer (score 0):

How about adding these settings?

Just you need to handle droppable settings for helper

```
appendTo: 'body',
containment: 'window',
scroll: false,
helper: 'clone',

start: function(){
    $(this).hide();             
},
stop: function(){
    $(this).show()
},
```

https://jsfiddle.net/74ghtq6x/1/

Comment: It work but I want show box after drop in other box. It show in same place. I think this clone solve my question but not solve that show problem inside other box.